# django template inheritance and context

Tags: django, django-templates

I am reading the definitive guide to django and am in Chapter 4 on template inheritance. It seems that I am not doing something as elegant as should be possible as I am having to duplicate some code for the context to appear when calling the child view.  Here is the code in views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_section = 'Temporary Home Page'
    return render_to_response("base.html", locals())
def contact(request):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_section = 'Contact page'
    return render_to_response("contact.html", locals())
```

It seems redundant to have to include the current_date line in each function.

Here is the base html file that homepage calls:

```
<html lang= "en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The Site</h1>
    {% block content %}
        <p> The Current section is {{ current_section }}.</p>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
    <p>The current time is {{ current_date }}</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and a child template file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Contact{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Contact information goes here...</p>
    <p>You are in the section {{ current_section }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

If I don't include the current_date line when calling the child file, where that variable should appear is blank.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass a variable to every template by using a [Context Processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

## 1. Adding the context processor to your settings file

First, you will need to **add** your custom Context Processor to your `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'myapp.context_processors.default', # add this line
    'django.core.context_processors.auth', 
)
```

From that you can derive that you will need to create a module called `context_processors.py` and place it inside your app's folder. You can further see that it will need to declare a function called `default` (as that's what we included in `settings.py`), but this is arbitrary. You can choose whichever function name you prefer.

## 2. Creating the Context Processor

```
# context_processors.py

from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings  # this is a good example of extra
                                  # context you might need across templates
def default(request):
    # you can declare any variable that you would like and pass 
    # them as a dictionary to be added to each template's context:
    return dict(
        example = "This is an example string.",
        current_date = datetime.now(),                
        MEDIA_URL = settings.MEDIA_URL, # just for the sake of example
    )
```

## 3. Adding the extra context to your views

The final step is to process the additional context using [`RequestContext()`](https://www.gartner.com/doc/3124817) and pass it to the template as a variable. Below is a very simplistic example of the kind of modification to the `views.py` file that would be required:

```
# old views.py
def homepage(request):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_section = 'Temporary Home Page'
    return render_to_response("base.html", locals())

def contact(request):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_section = 'Contact page'
    return render_to_response("contact.html", locals())


# new views.py
from django.template import RequestContext

def homepage(request):
    current_section = 'Temporary Home Page'
    return render_to_response("base.html", locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def contact(request):
    current_section = 'Contact page'
    return render_to_response("contact.html", locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you can use django.views,generic.simple.direct_to_template instead of render_to_response. It uses RequestContext internaly.

```
from django.views,generic.simple import direct_to_template

def homepage(request):
    return direct_to_template(request,"base.html",{
        'current_section':'Temporary Home Page'
    })

def contact(request):
    return direct_to_template(request,"contact.html",{
        'current_section':'Contact Page'
    })
```

Or you can even specify it directly at urls.py such as

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^/home/$','direct_to_template',{
        'template':'base.html'
        'extra_context':{'current_section':'Temporary Home Page'},        
    }),
    (r'^/contact/$','direct_to_template',{
        'template':'contact.html'
        'extra_context':{'current_section':'Contact page'},        
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

For django v1.8+ variables returned inside [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) can be accessed.

## 1. Add the context processor to your `TEMPLATES` list inside *`settings.py`*

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

               'your_app.context_processor_file.func_name',  # add this line

           ],
       },
   },
]
```

## 2. Create new file for context processor and define method for context

*`context_processor_file.py`*

```
def func_name(request):
  test_var = "hi, this is a variable from context processor"
  return {
    "var_for_template" : test_var,
  }
```

## 3. Now you can get the `var_for_template` in any templates

for example, add this line inside: *`base.html`*

```
<h1>{{ var_for_template }}</h1>
```

this will render:

```html
<h1>hi, this is a variable from context processor</h1>
```

for updating templates to django 1.8+ follow [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/)